# Error in My Query in MS Access with Brackets

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Good Morning ,

I keep getting an invalid bracket error and I cannot find the source of the error. My schema query is below. What is the source of my error?

```
INSERT INTO CombinedCommts ([Commit Type], [Sales Column], Column1, [No.])

SELECT [Commit Type], [Sales Column], Column1, [No.]

FROM ([Fleet Commit] JOIN [Shopko Commit] ON [Fleet Commit].[Commit Type]=[Shopko Commit].[Commit Type], [Shopko Commit].[Sales Column]=[Fleet Commit].[Sales Column], [Shopko Commit].[Column1]=[Fleet Commit].[Column1], [Shopko Commit].[No.]=[Fleet Commit].[No.]) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The bracket around the `join` couldn't work like that.
Each item of `where` clause have to be separated by `and` and not `,`.

Put more information of your datas, structure etc...

In Access you can use the SQL Wizard.

Comment: ok I fixed that error. Now I am having complication that I can only properly run a Left or Right Join or Inner and it only returns data from one table.

Comment: ELECT [Fleet Commit].[Commit Type], [Fleet Commit].[Sales Column], [Fleet Commit].Column1, [Fleet Commit].[No], [Fleet Commit].Gender, [Fleet Commit].Style, [Fleet Commit].[Style Descr], [Fleet Commit].Short, [Fleet Commit].[Product Line]

Comment: INTO ConstantCommits
FROM [Fleet Commit]  JOIN [Shopko Commit] ON ([Fleet Commit].[Sales Column] = [Shopko Commit].[Sales Column]) AND ([Fleet Commit].[Commit Type] = [Shopko Commit].[Commit Type]) AND ([Fleet Commit].Column1 = [Shopko Commit].Column1) AND ([Fleet Commit].[No] = [Shopko Commit].[No]) AND ([Fleet Commit].Gender = [Shopko Commit].Gender) AND ([Fleet Commit].Style = [Shopko Commit].Style) AND ([Fleet Commit].[Style Descr] = [Shopko Commit].[Style Descr]) AND ([Fleet Commit].[Product Line] = [Shopko Commit].[Product Line])

Comment: SELECT [Fleet Commit].[Commit Type], [Fleet Commit].[Sales Column], [Fleet Commit].Column1, [Fleet Commit].[No], [Fleet Commit].Gender, [Fleet Commit].Style, INTO ConstantCommits
FROM [Fleet Commit]  JOIN [Shopko Commit] ON ([Fleet Commit].[Sales Column] = [Shopko Commit].[Sales Column]) AND ([Fleet Commit].[Commit Type] = [Shopko Commit].[Commit Type]) AND ([Fleet Commit].Column1 = [Shopko Commit].Column1) AND ([Fleet Commit].[No] = [Shopko Commit].[No]) AND ([Fleet Commit].Gender = [Shopko Commit].Gender) AND ([Fleet Commit].Style = [Shopko Commit].Style)

Comment: Replace `join` by `left join` to test your datas.